# Does calling HashMap.entrySet() instantiate and populate a new set every time?

Tags: java

I have need of iterating over some HashMaps on each frame of an OpenGL loop. I do it like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<MyKey, MyValue> entry : myMap.entrySet(){...}
```

My concern is about whether this call to `entrySet()` actually instantiates and populates a brand new Map.Entry object every time it's called, because if it is, the GC will be more busy than I'd like when animating in OpenGL. My gut says no, because the HashMap documentation says that you can directly modify the HashMap using the returned entry set, but I don't know how to tell for sure.

And I'd also like to know about other Map implementations as well, like Hashtable, TreeMap, and LinkedHashMap.

Comment: The JDK source code is public information, just look it up.

Comment: Three years in, and I didn't know that!

Comment: Also, your JDK installation should contain a `src.zip` with all the source which you link to an IDE.

Comment: Weird that two people think this should be closed for being too broad. The answer is either yes or no. Can't get less broad than that. Leaving this open could be helpful to others. If someone else had ever asked this on SO, it would have saved me 15 minutes of browsing and comprehending the HashMap source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `HashMap.entrySet` is simply a cheap view, and takes O(1) time to create every time you call it.  The entry objects you get by iterating over it are, in fact, the objects used by the map to implement its internal data structures.

(That, and there's really no other way to do the things you would want to do with it.)

Comment: All three of these answers provide complementary info, but this was a helpful way of looking at it. In my case I'm not so concerned about creation time. Just don't want to be instantiating and allowing release of many small objects, because the GC can cause animation hiccups.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the source, the answer is no. It lazily instantiates the entry set on the first call to `entrySet()` and then returns a reference to the same object on each subsequent call.

The same is true for LinkedHashMap, Hashtable, and TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not create a new Set, rather a light-weight wrapper, like eg. Arrays.asList does, API says `The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.`